# TFS Build - System.Net.Http versioning issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm having a problem building my project using TFS 2015 Build.  First, the VS2015 project builds locally and runs correctly.

I need to reference a version of System.Net.Http that supports async in a library module.  So I installed NuGet version 4.3.3.  This has a DLL version number of 4.1.1.2.  I also installed the NuGet version in the DLL that I'm trying to build.

When I try to build the project using TFS build, I'm getting the below error message

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets
>   (1605): The primary reference "xxxxxxx" could not be resolved because
>   it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly
>   "System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.2, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which has a higher version "4.1.1.2"
>   than the version "4.0.0.0" in the current target framework.

Version 4.0.0.0 is the default version that is .net 4.6.1.  When I look into the project file, it correctly references the NuGet version, not the .net version.